# Cannot install a npm package (ts-patch: command not found)

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npm-install

#### Background

I am working on a CLI project, wrapping Git.

I made it with Node.js and have just published to npm. ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitove))

#### The problem

However, I cannot install this package both locally and globally. I get these errors below,

```
npm i -g gitove
```

Output:

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/lib/node_modules/gitove
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- ts-patch install
npm ERR! sh: ts-patch: command not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2023-08-15T11_36_43_711Z-debug-0.log
```

And:

```
npm i gitove
```

Output:

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/me/temp/node_modules/gitove
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- ts-patch install
npm ERR! sh: ts-patch: command not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2023-08-15T12_22_10_445Z-debug-0.log
```

It keeps requiring to have *ts-patch* installed. I first moved *ts-patch* to production dependencies and published again. Then, npm requires to have TypeScript installed. This doesn't seem right, and I'm assuming I made some mistakes in the build.

#### Build configuration

I wrote in TypeScript and compiled with [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) in order to convert import paths into ESM compatible paths with extensions and to set the alias path.

Why use ESM? Because inquirer and execa latest versions are ESM only, and because as an end service, I don't have to consider [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) compatibility for dependents.

##### File *bable.config.json*

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "src": "./src"
        }
      }
    ],
    "module-extension-resolver",
    "babel-plugin-transform-import-meta"
  ]
}
```

Any idea, please?

#### What I've tried

- Tried to move ts related devDependencies to dependencies, but this doesn't look right.
- Removed `"types"` in `package.json` assuming npm is considering my package as a TS package.
- Replaced `typia` to manual type guard, as I thought *typia* and its related dependencies are required in production. But, this didn't change the error message - "ts-path: command not found"